# Paypal Implement refunds

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm trying to integrate "Paypal smart buttons" in my webpage which was with a deprecated paypal implementation.
On this new integration I'm using server-side SDK and I can create and capture an order and save data in my DB.

The problem I have now is to implement the refund.
On my last implementation I had an IPN Listener and whenever I get a refund I could register it in my BD.
Since now IPN listener is deprecated, how can I implemented the "listener function"? Is the webhooks the new approach to implement the listener? I know that with [Webhooks Management API](https://developer.paypal.com/api/webhooks/v1/) I can list all webhooks events, but then how can I related them with the payment made and registered before in my BD?

I've already read lots of official paypal documentation but this is no clear to me, yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Register a webhook listener URL for the events you want, including refunds.

When you receive a refund webhook event at that URL, the body of the webhook will contain information about the capture/payment object (transaction id) that was refunded.

If in addition to the capture/transaction id you need some additional id for reconciliation purposes, there are two pieces of information you can include in the original order creation.

- an `invoice_id`, which is essentially your system's unique order ID. It must be unique, never used before for a successful completed transaction since it is used to block any future duplicate (accidental) payment attempts of the same ID.
- a `custom_id`, which can have any arbitrary value and is not indexed and not visible to the payer.